# How to find characters common to two stringBuffers?

Tags: java, string, character, stringbuffer

I am tring this method to find the common characters in two stringBuffers by returning a stringBuffer. without using arrays.  Please tell me what errors I am making.

```
private StringBuffer stringBuffer1;
private StringBuffer stringBuffer2;
public commonCharacters(String s1, String s2) {
    stringBuffer1 = new StringBuffer(s1);
    stringBuffer2 = new StringBuffer(word2);
}
String commonChars = "";
for (i = 0; i < stringBuffer1.length; i++) {
    char c = stringBuffer1.charAt(i);
    if (s2.indexOf(c) != -1) {
        commonChars = commonChars + c;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are characters in common? Characters at the same index?

Comment: Say if you said word 1 = "mouse" and word two = "houses" then the stringBuffer commonChars would return "ouse" as these are the characters common to both words.

Comment: What if I have "mouse" and "hhhhhhhhouse"?  Do you still consider them to have "ouse" in common?

Comment: Yes - its essentially just supposed to return characters that occur in both words

Comment: So "mouse" and "esuom" would have all 5 letters in common?

Comment: Yes - it doesn't matter what position the characters are in

Comment: And if there are multiple same characters?

Comment: If for example you had "dad" and "daddy" it would return "dad". So it would include multiple characters.

Comment: why dad and not dadd or da? I do not understand. Please detail the specifications exactly with a clear input and output.

Comment: Essentially we have to create a method which returns a StringBuffer that contains only the chars that occur in BOTH private StringBuffers. so since "dad" contains only two 'd's and one 'a', and daddy contains 3 d's, 1 a and 1 y, it would return the lowest number of d's and a's since these two characters are present in both words.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider that each character can appear multiple times in each String. A typical solution is to do that in two steps:
1) Build a map char -> number of occurrences for each of the two strings
2) Compare the maps to find common characters

```
Map<Character, Integer> charCount(String s) {
   Map<Character, Integer> mapCount = new HashMap<>();
   for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
      if (!s.contains(c)) mapCount.put(c, 1 + mapCount.computeIfAbsent(c, e -> 0));
   }
}

void findCommonCharacter(String s1, String s2) {
   Map<Character, Integer> m1 = charCount(s1);
   Map<Character, Integer> m2 = charCount(s2);
   for (char c : m1.keys()) {
      int occurrences = m2.containsKey(c) ? Math.min(m1.get(m1), m2.get(m2) : 0;
      if (occurrences>0) {
          System.out.println("The two strings share " + occurrences 
                   + " occurrences of " + c);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Whilst I understand how the above method works, we haven't yet been taught how to use the map.char() method therefore I don't think our teacher intended for us to use them. If there any other way of doing it?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but this is about solving a problem, not writing the solution to your homework :)

Comment: I've attempted to write a piece of code (above) but I'm not entirely sure why it doesn't work

Comment: With Java 8 you can use `mapCount.put(c, 1 + mapCount.computeIfAbsent(c, e -> 0))` instead of testing with contains and putting a zero in first. Also, `for (char c : s)` doesn't work, sadly; try using `for (char c : s.toCharArray())` instead.

Comment: Thanks David, I did not know about computeIfAbsent

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using arrays, we'll fill arrays of a length of 26 and get back to them to know how many of each letter there are in each word and compare both to take the minimum value.

---

### Solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("dad");
    StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer("daddy");
    System.out.println(findCommons(sb1, sb2)); // Prints "add"
    sb1 = new StringBuffer("Encapsulation");
    sb2 = new StringBuffer("Programmation");
    System.out.println(findCommons(sb1, sb2)); // Prints "aainopt"
}

public static StringBuffer findCommons(StringBuffer b1, StringBuffer b2){
    int[] array1 = new int[26];
    int[] array2 = new int[26];
    int[] common = new int[26];
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < (b1.length() < b2.length() ? b2:b1).length() ; i++){
        if (i < b1.length()) array1[Character.toLowerCase(b1.charAt(i)) - 'a'] += 1;
        if (i < b2.length()) array2[Character.toLowerCase(b2.charAt(i)) - 'a'] += 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 26 ; i++){
        common[i] = array1[i] < array2[i] ? array1[i] : + array2[i];
        for (int j = 0 ; j < common[i] ; j++) sb.append((char)('a' + i));
    }
    return sb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set intersection - you only need 3 lines of code:

```
Set<Character> common = stringBuffer1.toString().chars()
  .mapToObj(c -> Character.valueOf((char)c)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
common.retainAll(stringBuffer2.toString().chars()
  .mapToObj(c -> Character.valueOf((char)c)).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(common.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining("")));
```

But you shouldn't be using StringBuffer for this; just working with Strings will do it more easily:

```
public static String commonCharacters(String s1, String s2) {
    Set<String> chars = Arrays.stream(s1.split("")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    chars.retainAll(Arrays.stream(s2.split("")).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    return chars.stream().reduce((a,  b) -> a + b).get();
}
```